# How to use functions defined in assembler code in golang?

Tags: assembly, go

In golangs AES crypto package [cipher_amd64.go](https://golang.org/src/crypto/aes/cipher_amd64.go) makes use of functions that are defined in assembler code ([asm_amd64.s](https://golang.org/src/crypto/aes/asm_amd64.s)). In the mentioned go file only the function headers are defined:

```
// defined in asm_amd64.s
func encryptBlockAsm(nr int, xk *uint32, dst, src *byte)
func decryptBlockAsm(nr int, xk *uint32, dst, src *byte)
func expandKeyAsm(nr int, key *byte, enc *uint32, dec *uint32)
```

How can I use these functions in my own code? Just declaring the headers and importing "crypto/aes" as in the mentioned .go file does not work (`undefined: expandKeyAsm`).

Thank you very much!

Comment: The functions are not exported so you cannot use them.

Comment: As the source code is available how can I make them accessible in my code? Go has no header files but the assembler file uses `#include "textflag.h"` for example.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use something like `aes.NewCipher(your_aes_key)` to create a new `cipher.Block` for use with the various functions in the `crypto/cipher` package to encrypt/decrypt as necessary?

Comment: Use the high level functions, maybe even golang.org/x/crypto/nacl and stay away from the hairy details from crypto implementations.

Comment: Yes, in general it's bad practice to brew your own crypto soup. But I'm trying to implement an algorithm that slightly differs from the original AES. Therefore I have some cases for that I need to have access to the lower level functions. `aes.NewCipher(your_aes_key)` should fit my needs but I want to run the encryption without the InitialRound and FinalRound of the AES algorithm.

Comment: Then copy the parts you need and put them in your own lib.

Comment: @RickyA but how can I copy the assembly code? I don't understand how can I connect it to my code. It looks like a c file as it has a header import!?

Comment: copy the asm_amd64.s and the cipher_amd64.go files to your project. The .s file will compile automaticly. Then go dependency hunting (aka strip everything you don't need)

Comment: https://goroutines.com/asm and https://golang.org/doc/asm

Comment: @RickyA thank you! That's the information I asked for.

Comment: Your welcome. I put it in a answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy the `asm_amd64.s` contents over to your package
2. Define the functions somewehere in that package
3. Use those functions in the package

Example (with the asm_amd64.s in the same package):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func encryptBlockAsm(nr int, xk *uint32, dst, src *byte)
func decryptBlockAsm(nr int, xk *uint32, dst, src *byte)
func expandKeyAsm(nr int, key *byte, enc *uint32, dec *uint32)

func main() {
    var nr int
    var xk uint32
    var dst byte
    var src byte

    fmt.Printf("Before:\t%v, %v, %v, %v\n", nr, xk, dst, src)

    encryptBlockAsm(nr, &xk, &dst, &src)

    fmt.Printf("After:\t%v, %v, %v, %v\n", nr, xk, dst, src)
}
```

Yields:

```
Before: 0, 0, 0, 0
After:  0, 0, 231, 173
```

I have no idea what the inputs should be but at least it demonstrates this does something :)